# Changing rows to columns through merging in R

Tags: r, merge, rows, calculated-columns

```
actual_date=c('2018-01-03','2018-01-02','2018-01-25','2018-01-15','2018-01-06','2018-01-02','2018-01-16','2018-01-22','2018-01-03')
date_band=c('_201801','_201801','_201803','_201802','_201801', '_201801','_201803','_201804','_201801')


    action=c('text','letter','call','letter','visit','letter','text','text','call')
unique_ref=c(1,1,2,1,2,3,3,4,4)
df1=as.data.frame(cbind(unique_ref,actual_date,date_band,action))

unique_ref=c(1,2,3,4)
priority_201801=c('3','2','3','0')
balance_201801=c('30','-20','35','-100')
priority_201802=c('1','1','1','2')
balance_201802=c('60','-40','35','0')
priority_201803=c('2','2','3','2')
balance_201803=c('30','-40','-50','100')
priority_201804=c('99','0','0','0')
balance_201804=c('0','-20','-50','-100')


df2=as.data.frame(cbind(unique_ref,priority_201801,balance_201801,priority_201802,balance_201802,priority_201803,
                        balance_201803,priority_201804,balance_201804))
```

The code above produces two examples of datasets I'm working with.

df1 looks like this:

```
  unique_ref actual_date date_band action
1          1  2018-01-03   _201801   text
2          1  2018-01-02   _201801 letter
3          2  2018-01-25   _201803   call
4          1  2018-01-15   _201802 letter
5          2  2018-01-06   _201801  visit
6          3  2018-01-02   _201801 letter
7          3  2018-01-16   _201803   text
8          4  2018-01-22   _201804   text
9          4  2018-01-03   _201801   call
```

While df2 looks like:

```
  unique_ref priority_201801 balance_201801 priority_201802 balance_201802 priority_201803 balance_201803 priority_201804 balance_201804
1          1               3             30               1             60               2             30              99              0
2          2               2            -20               1            -40               2            -40               0            -20
3          3               3             35               1             35               3            -50               0            -50
4          4               0           -100               2              0               2            100               0           -100
```

What I want to do is add a column to df2 that states action_dateband (i.e. action_201801, action_201802 etc). This would be taken from the action in df1 using the date_band and matched on unqiue_ref.

Desired output looks as follows: Where if there are two for one week, there is a comma between the two actions.

```
  unique_ref priority_201801 balance_201801 action_201801 priority_201802 balance_201802 action_201802 priority_201803 balance_201803 action_201803
1          1               3             30   text,letter               1             60        letter               2             30              
2          2               2            -20         visit               1            -40                             2            -40          call
3          3               3             35        letter               1             35                             3            -50          text
4          4               0           -100          call               2              0                             2            100              
  priority_201804 balance_201804 action_201804
1              99              0              
2               0            -20              
3               0            -50              
4               0           -100          text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by=c("unique_ref")) %>%                # join df1 to df2
  select(-actual_date) %>%                              # remove column you won't need
  mutate(date_band = paste0("action", date_band)) %>%   # update column values
  spread(date_band, action)                             # reshape to get the format you want


#   unique_ref priority_201801 balance_201801 priority_201802 balance_201802 priority_201803 balance_201803
# 1          1               3             30               1             60               2             30
# 2          2               2            -20               1            -40               2            -40
# 3          3               3             35               1             35               3            -50
# 4          4               0           -100               2              0               2            100
#     priority_201804 balance_201804 action_201801 action_201802 action_201803 action_201804
#   1              99              0          text        letter          <NA>          <NA>
#   2               0            -20         visit          <NA>          call          <NA>
#   3               0            -50        letter          <NA>          text          <NA>
#   4               0           -100          call          <NA>          <NA>          text
```

For the case where you have multiple actions for a specific `ref` and `date_band` you can use this approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

# update df1
df1_upd = df1 %>%
  group_by(unique_ref, date_band) %>%                     # for every combination of ref and date_band
  summarise(action = paste0(action, collapse = ",")) %>%  # combine actions
  ungroup()                                               # forget the grouping


df2 %>%
  left_join(df1_upd, by=c("unique_ref")) %>%                
  mutate(date_band = paste0("action", date_band)) %>% 
  spread(date_band, action)

#   unique_ref priority_201801 balance_201801 priority_201802 balance_201802 priority_201803 balance_201803
# 1          1               3             30               1             60               2             30
# 2          2               2            -20               1            -40               2            -40
# 3          3               3             35               1             35               3            -50
# 4          4               0           -100               2              0               2            100
#     priority_201804 balance_201804 action_201801 action_201802 action_201803 action_201804
#   1              99              0   text,letter        letter          <NA>          <NA>
#   2               0            -20         visit          <NA>          call          <NA>
#   3               0            -50        letter          <NA>          text          <NA>
#   4               0           -100          call          <NA>          <NA>          text
```

Comment: Thanks for this!! I think this will work! One question, what if I have multiple actions for one date band? Is there a way to make that work? I'd be happy to have a column for each action, or list the actions with commas in one cell.

Comment: You can have multiple rows (a row for each action value), or combine actions (have a value combination separated with commas, as you said). Best thing to do is update your answer including an example like this, or post another question.

Comment: I've added a solution to this case.

Comment: I've just noticed that I get multiple rows for the Unique ref, so one row will have the action for action_201801 but then a different row for action_201802 instead of being on the same row?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure how is that possible. Can you create an example where my code has this issue? I'll find out why this happens and will try to fix it.

Comment: I'll try and get that sorted now, I have to let you know though that this only happens with my bigger dataset and not with the example one above. So, maybe actually you won't be able to help me? The actual dataset has 585 variables.

Comment: Maybe if you can isolate the `ref` and `action` columns that this happens and focus on those?

Comment: It was only happening when I had the whole dataset so I took ref, action and date_band to a separate dataset then applied spread() then merged it back onto the big dataset. This got me to where I needed to be. I'll try and investigate further when I have some downtime. Thanks for all your help!